# Retrieve a value from multiple xml nodes and xml attributes in DB2

Tags: db2

Need help to retrieve a value under multiple xml nodes and xml attributes. Below is the xml and the query. I am trying get ID 12945 from agent2 .Any help greatly appreciated.

```
 <Message>
    <PartyRole xsi:type="isf:Agent1"/>
        <Id>12645</Id>
    </PartyRole>
    <PartyRole xsi:type="isf:Agent2"/>
        <Id>12945</Id>
    </PartyRole>                        
    <PartyRole xsi:type="isf:Agent3">
        <Id>52345</Id>
    </PartyRole>                        
 <Message>
```

Query:
`XMLCAST(XMLQUERY('$file/*:Message/*:PartyRole/*:PartyRole[@xsi = "isf:Agent2"]/*:Id' PASSING XMLPARSE(DOCUMENT T1."XML_COLUMN") AS "file") AS CHAR(5)) AS AgentID`

Comment: `xsi` is the namespace. your attribute name is `type`

Comment: your xml does not seem to be a valid one.  1st of all you need to get a valid xml.  ' XMLPARSE() function returns SQL16193N for it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your xml is not valid! or you have just pasted a portion of it.

You have a namespace alias, that is not defined anywhere  `xsi`.
Also, first two   nodes are self-closed,  the the "childs" are hanging...

Anyway.

I tried to "guess" what would be your good xml... If using this one:

```
<Message xmlns:xsi="anything">
    <PartyRole xsi:type="isf:Agent1">
        <Id>12645</Id>
    </PartyRole>
    <PartyRole xsi:type="isf:Agent2">
        <Id>12945</Id>
    </PartyRole>                        
    <PartyRole xsi:type="isf:Agent3">
        <Id>52345</Id>
    </PartyRole>                        
 </Message>
```

Following query works as your desire:

```
with goodxml(cxml) as  ( values xmlparse( document ' <Message xmlns:xsi="anything">
    <PartyRole xsi:type="isf:Agent1">
        <Id>12645</Id>
    </PartyRole>
    <PartyRole xsi:type="isf:Agent2">
        <Id>12945</Id>
    </PartyRole>                        
    <PartyRole xsi:type="isf:Agent3">
        <Id>52345</Id>
    </PartyRole>                        
 </Message>' ) )

SELECT XMLCAST( XMLQUERY('$file/Message/PartyRole[@*:type="isf:Agent2"]/Id' 
                   PASSING CXML AS "file") AS CHAR(5)) AS AgentID 
    FROM goodxml
```

---

```
AGENTID
-------
12945

  1 record(s) selected.
```